# Find the square root using a recursive formula

Tags: numerics, recursion, homework

I want to approximate the square root `x=Sqrt[a]`  for $a>0$ using the the formula $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+a/x_n)$. How can I do this?

Comment: `f[a_?(# > 0 &)] := FixedPoint[(# + a/#)/2 &, 1.]`

Comment: thank you for your help this is not recursive style

Comment: Then what do you mean by "recursive style"? What have you tried?

Comment: if you know the recursive style then you will know what i am try to do

Comment: The code given by @Bob in the comment is exactly the recursive style I know, if it's not the recursive style in your mind, you should clarify your question rather than let us guess. Also, this site is not a free coding service, so please show us your effort.

Comment: i am forced to write this formula in procedural ,functional ,and recursive , I am already did it for procedural and functional but when it is comes to recursive i tried a lot but still miss something that is why i come here and aske ... if i were wrong so i am sorry i am beginner ..

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_?(# > 0 &)] := Module[{x, m = 1},
  x[0] = 1.;
  x[n_] := x[n] = (x[n - 1] + a/x[n - 1])/2;
  While[x[m]^2 != a, m++];
  x[m]]

f[#] - Sqrt[#] & /@ {2, E, Pi, Prime[17]}

(* {-2.22045*10^-16, 0., 0., 4.26326*10^-14} *)
```

A more straightforward method of recursion is to use [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_?(# > 0 &)] := FixedPoint[(# + a/#)/2 &, 1.]

f[#] - Sqrt[#] & /@ {2, E, Pi, Prime[17]}

(* {-2.22045*10^-16, 0., 0., 8.88178*10^-16} *)
```

Comment: thank you soooo much

Comment: You can simplify the pattern to `f[a_?Positive] := ...`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an implementation in about as pure a recursive style as you can hope for. It is fully tail-recursive, so it has the same efficiency as an iterative implementation.

```
sqrt[_, r1_, r0_] /; r1 == r0 := r1
sqrt[u_, r1_, r0_] := sqrt[u, (r1 + u/r1)/2., r1]
sqrt[u_] /; u >= 0 := sqrt[u, u/2., 0.]
```

Then

```
nums = {2, E, Pi, Prime[17]};
rts = sqrt /@ nums
rts^2
```

gives

> ```
> {1.41421, 1.64872, 1.77245, 7.68115} 
> {2., 2.71828, 3.14159, 59.}
> ```